# How to tell what is in committed and reserved memory?

Tags: c++, windbg, crash-dumps

I am currently looking into an issue where an application is using alot of private memory for a C++ app.  It looks like alot is in committed and reserve memory based on the dump analysis.

I use Windbg.  Is there any way I can see what excactly is in commited and reserve memory?  I have narrowed it down to one specific heap.

My theory is that it's not being released.  I cannot live debug, I only have dumps to go on.

Any suggestions would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`!address -Filter` should be able to give that information. Here are the different filter options.

> MEM_COMMIT :-  All memory that is
>   currently committed for use by the
>   target. Physical storage has been
>   allocated for this memory, in physical
>   memory or in the page file.
>
> MEM_RESERVE :-  All memory that is
>   reserved for future use by the target.
>   No physical storage is  allocated for
>   this memory.
>
> MEM_FREE :-  All available memory in
>   the target's virtual address space.
>   This memory includes all memory that
>   has not been committed or reserved.
>   This Filter value is the same as
>   RegionUsageFree.

Comment: Thanks, so I got this nice little output.  What do i do with it?

Comment: This blog should help you http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/02/15/net-debugging-demos-lab-3-memory.aspx